# What if a courier steals my personal information

Tags: passport, italy, identity-theft, postal-service

Since I recently moved in another country (Italy), I wanted to obtain a local phone number. After I applied online for my new SIM card, I had to provide the telephony company with a copy of an identity document (in my case, my passport) upon receiving my card through snail mail. So, when the courier arrived, I received the envelope with my card and gave him the copy.

In retrospect, I’m thinking that I did something stupid, because, even though the telephony and shipping companies are certified and generally reliable, the courier himself could use this copy for identity theft.

Is it probable that this courier could do something like that, considering that he is employed by a known company and the envelope has his name on it? Or am I overthinking?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking whether it's likely that a person did a particular act, which is not a question about the law.

Comment: Is your question asking about whether the courier could commit some sort of identity theft with the information you provided or is it about what kind of recourse you would have in the event identity theft did occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A courier **could** open the envelope and steal the ID information inside. Whether this is likely depends on how carefully the company is in selecting couriers, and what action the company, and local law enforcement would take if such a thing were reported. There is no way to know that in general, and it might vary for different companies.

I have known of US Postal Service employees who improperly opened mail. How frequent such improper action is I cannot say.